# Failed to load JVM DLL - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have installed Android Studio on my Windows 10 PC and I have encountered an error when starting it. I get this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbudW.png)

I have set JAVA_HOME in my system environmental variables, I tried setting it both in User and System Variables, but it's always the same error.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2niC.png)

When I type in javac -version and java -version in command prompt it gives me the correct java version with no errors.

I had this error with older versions of Java JDK as well..

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with you.
Goto this location:
C:\Users\yourName\
and delete the ".AndroidStudio2.3" folder you have there.
I just did mine and it works.
Note that I used "AndroidStudio2.3" because mine is version2.3.
in other words, the version number should be replaced with the version number of your Android Studio.